# PSK5 padding in C++

Tags: java, c++, encryption, password-encryption

I am trying to achieve a AES encryption in both Java and C++ programming. Basically the Java will send an encrypted message to a device that has a program written in C++ language.

In the Java side to pad the secret key that will encrypt and decrypt the message, I used the PSK5 padding style in ECB mode.
In the C++ side I am trying to achieve the same result.

I wrote some code and I wanted to ask if this is a good approach or if I should try someone else.

```
string input = "ciao!";

char pad[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
if(input.length() % 8 != 0)
{
   int missingLength = 8 - (input.length() % 8 );
    for (int i = 0; i<missingLength; i++)
    {
       input += pad[missingLength];
    }

}
```

Comment: Might be better on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also the array has 9 elements and you are performing % 8 across the board. Is this your intention?

Comment: Oh, that was an error, my intent is only from 01 to 08 bytes that I want to add to my key to pad it. 
apart from that
Is it incorrect? I haven't found any code related to that and I am still very new to encryption.

Comment: Why don't you use the Cypto++ library to do the heavy lifting for you? https://www.cryptopp.com/

Comment: Do you mean PKCS5?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a full size key, 16, 24 or 32 bytes. If your key is to short or you are using a password use a key derivation function such as PBKDFG2 to create a full length secure key.
2. Use PKCS5 (PKCS7) to pad the data, it should just be an option so there should be no need to do it manually in your code.
3. Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.

Consider using a cross-platform/language solution such as [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), that can provide key derivation as well as authentication.

Comment: I am not sure if RNCryptor would be compatible with the arduino board but I will have a look.
And Excuse me, my question was not related to the key but as you said to the data.
Mine is just a simple example, my encryption does not need to be extremely secure I just wanted to try and get the same algorithm that Java uses in the ECB/PKCS5 cipher mode. I wanted to achieve the same result on my C++ program, since that will decrypt the message.
As far as you know, do you know any library that could do that for me and is compatible with arduino? Or can I write code to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Secret keys aren't padded at all. If anything is padded it is the plaintext message (don't be fooled by the word plaintext, AES works on bits/bytes).

PKCS#5 padding, or - for a block cipher with a 128 bit block size - rather PKCS#7 padding *always* pads the plaintext. This makes it possible to encrypt any kind of plaintext message, even if it ends with bytes that could be interpreted as padding bytes.

It seems to me you should use a previously generated library such as OpenSSL of Crypto++ and not create your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
You really need to excuse me, I made a mistake with my question. What I wanted to pad is actually the "plaintext" data. From what I was reading, I thought you could have added simple characters based on the bytes that you need to pad.
As far as you know, Open SSL of Crypto++ will that be compatible with the arduino board? 
And Will I be able to achieve the same result as the ECB/PKCS#5 of JAVA?